# I want to make the character run faster if I press the key twice in a row in a game

Tags: python, pygame

It's part of the code I wrote.

```
enter code here
    import pygame
    from pygame.locals import QUIT, KEYDOWN, KEYUP,\
        K_LEFT, K_RIGHT, K_DOWN, K_SPACE, K_UP
    pygame.init()
    pygame.key.set_repeat(30, 30)
    while True:
        to_x1 = 0
        for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.quit()
                keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
                if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
                    to_x1 = -5
                if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
                    to_x1 = 5
        CHARIC_1.xpos1 = CHARIC_1.xpos1 + to_x1
```

CHARIC_1.xpos1 is the character's x coordinate.
I want to make my character run faster when I hit the right or left key twice fast.
I don't know for the life of me. I'd like you to let me know if you know how.

Comment: What does "fast" mean? What is the rule that will tell you if the key presses were close enough together? And then what? How much faster should the character run? Should the character keep running at the same speed until... when? You need to think through the logic of what actually needs to happen, and then it will be straightforward: you just have to know what things you have to remember (e.g. "how long ago was it that the last keypress happened?") and what to do with that information.

Comment: But none of this is a good question for Stack Overflow. If you need help with *design*, you could try gamedev.stackexchange.com, but you are still going to need a more precise idea about how you want things to work.

Comment: Very simply, (1) define "fast"; (2) save the state of your keypresses into a variable; (3) research how to get the system time; add that to your keypress handler; (4) when you get a left or right keypress, then you check (a) is it the same as the previous one; (b) is it "close" to the previous one?  If so, then you increase your movement parameter to 10 or -10, as appropriate.

Comment: You can find an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61653596/142637)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the keyboard event `KEYDOWN` (see [`pygame.event`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html)) rather than [`pygame.key.get_pressed()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html#pygame.key.get_pressed). Use [`pygame.time.get_ticks()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.get_ticks) to get the number of milliseconds since `pygame.init()` was called. Store the time at which a key is pressed. If the button is pressed twice within a certain amount of time, increases the speed:

```py
key_time = 0
fast_key_time = 500 # 0.5 seconds

while True:
    current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

    # [...]

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        # [...]

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                if to_x1 == -5 and current_time < key_time + fast_key_time:
                    to_x1 = -10
                else:
                    to_x1 = -5
                key_time = current_time
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                if to_x1 == 5 and current_time < key_time + fast_key_time:
                    to_x1 = 10
                else:
                    to_x1 = 5
                key_time = current_time

    CHARIC_1.xpos1 = CHARIC_1.xpos1 + to_x1

    # [...]
```

---

Minimal example:

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, 20, 20)
rect.center = window.get_rect().center

to_x1 = 0
key_time = 0
fast_key_time = 500 # 0.5 seconds

run = True
while run:
    current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                if to_x1 == -5 and current_time < key_time + fast_key_time:
                    to_x1 = -10
                else:
                    to_x1 = -5
                key_time = current_time
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                if to_x1 == 5 and current_time < key_time + fast_key_time:
                    to_x1 = 10
                else:
                    to_x1 = 5
                key_time = current_time

    rect.x += to_x1
        
    rect.centerx = rect.centerx % window.get_width()
    rect.centery = rect.centery % window.get_height()

    window.fill(0)
    pygame.draw.rect(window, (255, 0, 0), rect)
    pygame.display.flip()
```